# How to get library variable / variable group usage in azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple library variable groups in azure pipelines.

These library groups are used by multiple build and release pipelines.

How can I check the library variable group usage in azure pipelines?

For example:

1. How to get a list of all pipelines that use a particular variable group?
2. How to get a list of all pipelines that use a particular variable from the variable group?

Comment: What kind of pipeline are you using,YAML or Classic UI pipeline?

Comment: Classic UI pipeline

Answer (score 3):

We do **not have this kind of feature** to track which Pipelines reference a Variable Group for **Release Pipeline** at the moment.

There used to be a similar question here:  [How to see which Release Pipelines reference a Variable Group?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5195)

> We have this ask in our backlog to show the variable group references
>   in the pipelines. As of now no timelines are finalized on this
>   feature. We will update once we decide on the timelines.

According to *ashokirla's* reply, we may not deploy this feature in the short-term.

---

But it's able to do with build, you could choose either manually export your build pipeline or use API to get a list of [Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) Definitions

[image]

They will be imported as  JSON files. Then you will be able to find variable group info in those JSON files such as below :

[image]

Use some search tool to track the variable group info in all JSON pipelines.

For single build definition:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

For multiple build definitions, add `&includeAllProperties=true` in the end of your API.

Comment: I checked build definition over REST API and there is no information about variables or variable groups :(

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Kindly check my update. For multiple build definitions, add `&includeAllProperties=true` in the end of your API.

Comment: When can I buy you a beer? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the above `&includeAllProperties=true` for *release pipeline* and it shows the `"variableGroups":null`. But in the UI I can see the variable groups. Is there any way to get this data for all release pipelines?

Comment: Hi @variable, sorry for the later reply. Could you share your full  rest api which you are using here?

Comment: It appears that release pipeline doesn't support `includeAllProperties=true`. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @variable There is a `$expand` URI Parameters. I am not in office. Could you give a try with ReleaseDefinitionExpands here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#releasedefinitionexpands   such as `$expand=variables` . Check if this do the trick

Comment: It does returns variables, but doesn't return variable groups

Comment: @variable I could reproduce this. I am afraid this is available with build pipeline but  **not available with release pipeline**. Just as *ashokirla* pointed out in this link: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5195  Also not able to use Rest API to handle this.  Even export the release pipeline  as a json file, get the same result.

Comment: A interesting thing here is if you created a release for related pipeline. You use[Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API to get a release, you will be able to  see variable group info and variables in that variable group. Hope it helps. Also updated my reply.